# What is the difference between output and output logic in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Here is example 1.

```
   module my_fsm(clk, reset, X, Y, Z);
     input clk, reset, X;
     output Y, Z;
   endmodule
```

And here is example 2.

```
module my_fsm(clk, reset, X, Y, Z);
 input clk, reset, X;
 output logic Y, Z;
endmodule
```

As you can see, there is `output Y, Z`, and there is `output logic Y, Z`. What is the fundamental difference between `output` and `output logic` in Verilog?

Comment: Based on 23.2.2.3 Rules for determining port kind, data type, and direction from IEEE 1800-2012 both your examples are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

logic keyword was introduced in system verilog. It avoids the confusion between a reg and wire.

```
input a;
output reg x; //x is declared as a register
always@(posedge clk)
 x <= a;
```

Another way of writing above block

```
input a;
output logic x; //Here x is taken as a register since its used inside always block
always@(posedge clk)
x <= a;

input a;
output logic x;
assign x = a; //Here x is taken as a wire due to assign statement
```

Comment: when no type on port is specified, `wire` is assumed. So, the difference is `wire` vs  `logic`.